# Introduction to Analysis: Continuity and Limits

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

My coworker and I were looking at a problem for our Real Analysis class. It reads:

> Call a function "multiplicatively periodic" if there is a positive number c $\neq$ 1 such that $f(cx) = f(x)$ for all x $\in$ R. Prove that if a multiplicatively periodic function is continuous at 0, then it is a constant function.

We were unsure either this is true or not. I want to say this isn't necessarily true. The function doesn't have to be a constant. Two examples that came to mind were $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$. They are periodic function where $f(cx) = f(x)$ and they are both continuous at $0$. We were later debating that our idea of sine and cosine could be wrong. If we had $f(x) = \sin{x}$ and x = $\pi$, then f(c$\pi$) = f($\pi$) for all c. However, f(c$\frac{\pi}{4}$) $\neq$ f($\frac{\pi}{4}$) for all c but some. I commented that the question does not necessarily say for all c, just for all x there exists $f(cx) = f(x)$. So the wording here is debatable. We could not come to a conclusion.

I want to disprove that "if a multiplicatively periodic function is continuous at 0, then it is a constant function."

If a function is constant then $f(x) = k$ for every a $\in$ $(-\infty , \infty)$.

My counterexamples would be either sine or cosine. To prevent negatives, properly $\sin{x}^2$ or $\cos{x}^2$. However, I am not sure how to go about and start the proof. My idea is we have two variables x and y that are elements in the interval. I want to go about and show that $f(cx) = f(x)$ and $f(cy) = f(y)$, but $f(x) \neq f(y)$. I want to simply disprove this by given the counterexample; however, I am not sure if I could do so. Thus, I decided to go about it with a proof where I eventually bring in a counterexample.

My attempt:

Proof:
Let $f(x)$ be a multiplicatively periodic function continuous on the interval $(-\infty , \infty)$ such that $f(cx) = f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is continuous at 0, then for all x $\in$ $(-\infty , \infty)$, f(x) = k.

Since $f(x)$ is a constant function, then $f(x) = k$ for every a $\in$ $(-\infty , \infty)$.

Let x, y $\in$ $(-\infty , \infty)$ such that $f(cx) = f(x)$ and $f(cy) = f(y)$.

Given an $\epsilon$ > 0, there is a $\delta$ > 0 such that |$f(x) - f(y)$|< $\epsilon$ and |$x - y$| < $\delta$. However, if f(x) = k for all x $\in$ $(-\infty , \infty)$ then $\epsilon$ = 0.

Thus by contradiction, $f(x)$ is not a constant function.

I know the proof is not correct nor complete, but I hope it is a step in the right direction. I want to properly introduce my counterexample but I am not sure where. I am more confused as to how to properly continue the proof.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and thanks to those in advance for your feedback.

Comment: There is _one_ positive $c \neq 1$ such that for __all__ $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you have $f(cx) = f(x)$. So $f(1) = f(c) = f(c^2) = f(c^3) = \dotsc = f(c^{-1}) = f(c^{-2}) = \dotsc$.

Comment: It is true that the statement does not say for all $c$. What it _is_ saying though is that there is one $c \neq 1$ which must work for every $x$. Be careful with the logical quantifiers here. The $c$ is chosen _first_ which then works for all $x$. It is __not__ that for every $x$ we can choose a $c$ after.

Comment: So c is chosen first. That being said sin(x) and cos(x) will not work. If I said c = 2. If works if x = pi. It will not work for x = pi/2. That being said, my original idea is properly wrong. Then f(x) has to be a constant function, right?

Answer (score 1):

$sin$ and $cos$ are not counterexamples to this statement, because they are "additively" periodic, so there is a $c\neq0$ such that $sin(x+c)=sin(x)$ for all $x$ (in this case $c=2\pi$).
But you will not find a $c\neq 1$ s.t. $sin(cx)=sin(x)$ for all x.

Your confusion stems from incorrectly applied predicate logic.
The problem states that there has to be **some** $c\neq1$, and after you have found that $c$, that statement works with all $x$. The direct negation of that statement would be "No matter what $c\neq1$ you choose, you will find an $x$ that does not follow the statement"

What your "counterexample" tries to prove is the statement "For every $x$, there is some $c\neq1$ for which the statement is not true."
This is not a contradiction to "There is a $c\neq1$, s.t. every $x$ satisfies" You might just not have found the *special* $c$.

Here is a hint on how to prove the statement that functions that are continuous in $0$ have to be constant:
Let's start with assuming that the *special* $c$ has $|c|<1$. Take any $x$ and look at $f(x)$. Now you see that $f(cx)$ takes the same value. And $f(c^2x)$ is also the same value and so on. Now if you keep multiplying $c$ to your $x$, where will you end up? You will find that $f(x)=f(0)$ no matter what $x$ you selected at the start.
The case for $|c|>1$ is similar, you may want to write $f(x)$ as $f(c^n \frac{x}{c^n})$